# Python: Summing up a float

Tags: python-2.7

If I have a list of strings stored in a variable called b_split[1]. Basically the 1st position in b_split contains these latitude values as a string.

> ['10.2']
>   ['10.4']
>   ['10.5']

I want to be able to sum them up..

```
for i in text_file:
    latitude = float(b_split[1])
print sum(latitude)
```

It gives me an error that the 'float' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

latitude should be a list

and it should be

```
latitude.append(float(b_split[1]))
```

and finally

```
print sum(latitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the resulting list and simply want to sum the items, you could try passing the items you care about directly to the `sum` function:

```
In [1]: my_list = ['10.2', '10.4', '10.5']

In [2]: sum(float(item) for item in my_list)
Out[2]: 31.1
```

This creates a [generator](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/GeneratorExpressions.html) of the `float` of each item in your list, and sums each item. As alluded to by @avasal, the reason you are getting your error is because you are actually reassigning `latitude` on each iteration, and your final result is a float (and not a list/iterable):

```
In [3]: for item in my_list:
   ...:     my_var = float(item)
   ...:     

In [4]: print my_var
10.5
```

Therefore when you try to `sum` it, you get the error you see above because sum [sums the elements of an iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum). Since you can't iterate over a `float`, you get the `not iterable` error.